# What is the difference between loading JS in FF & IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am currently working on a heavy web page. This page contains 5 tabs & each tab contains a gridview & multiple server controls. When i work in Edit mode I fetch data from database for all tabs using Ajax request & fill the controls using Jquery. This works fine in mozilla but IE 6 takes time to fill the controls because i think mozilla FF fills the controls sequentially but IE fills all controls asynchronously & displays when all controls are filled what is the best way to fill the controls in IE 6 faster way?

Comment: IE6 has a dog slow javascript engine, it's going to be quite noticeable if your js is doing a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer and FireFox and Chrome all use different Javascript Engines to each-other. Older versions of IE weren't optimized for heavy Javascript usages since back in the day Bandwidth was low so sending large libraries wasnt good. These days with higher bandwidth availablity, developers are able to make use of these, so new browsers have since optimized the performance of there engines to suite. Older browsers like IE6 are still stuck in 1999.

IE7 is heaps faster than IE6 while IE9 is now miles ahead IE7. Chrome, Safari and FF are all running micro-optimized engines like [V8](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fv8%2F&ei=1RoITsTuGumimQX73tHiDQ&usg=AFQjCNGT5gCr8wk2HMADYD-6jwej-y2V8A) and [TraceMonkey](http://arstechnica.com/news.ars/post/20080822-firefox-to-get-massive-javascript-performance-boost.html)

In reality, there isn't much you can do to make any HUGE performance improvments with the way your script works. In reality, those with IE6 should toss it like a 15 year old sandwich in your schoolbag